# Condensing Wide Data Based on Column Name

Tags: pandas

Is there an elegant way to do what I'm trying to do in Pandas? My data looks something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'alpha': [1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'bravo': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, -1],
    'charlie': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'delta': [np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan],
})

print(df)

   alpha  bravo  charlie  delta
0    1.0    NaN      NaN    NaN
1    NaN    NaN      NaN    1.0
2    NaN    NaN      NaN    NaN
3    NaN   -1.0      NaN    NaN
```

and I want to transform that into something like:

```
  position  value
0    alpha      1
1    delta      1
2      NaN    NaN
3    bravo     -1
```

So for each row in the original data I want to find the non-NaN value and retrieve the name of the column it was found in. Then I'll store the column and value in new columns called 'position' and 'value'.

I can guarantee that each row in the original data contains exactly zero or one non-NaN values.

My only idea is to iterate over each row but I know that idea is bad and there must be a more pandorable way to do it. I'm not exactly sure how to word my problem so I'm having trouble Googling for ideas. Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3):

We can use `DataFrame.melt` to un pivot your data, then use `sort_values` and `drop_duplicates`:

```
df = (
    df.melt(var_name='position')
    .sort_values('value')
    .drop_duplicates('position', ignore_index=True)
)
```

```
  position  value
0    bravo   -1.0
1    alpha    1.0
2    delta    1.0
3  charlie    NaN
```

---

Another option would be to use `DataFrame.bfill` over the column axis. Since you noted that:

> can guarantee that each row in the original data contains exactly zero or one non-NaN values

```
values = df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
dfn = pd.DataFrame({'positions': df.columns, 'values': values})
```

```
  positions  values
0     alpha     1.0
1     bravo     1.0
2   charlie     NaN
3     delta    -1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this. Actually, I just noticed, that it is quite similar to Erfan's first proposal:

```
# get the index as a column
df2= df.reset_index(drop=False)
# melt the columns keeping index as the id column
# and sort the result, so NaNs appear at the end
df3= df2.melt(id_vars=['index'])
df3.sort_values('value', ascending=True, inplace=True)
# now take the values of the first row per index
df3.groupby('index')[['variable', 'value']].agg('first')
```

Or shorter:
(
df.reset_index(drop=False)
.melt(id_vars=['index'])
.sort_values('value')
.groupby('index')[['variable', 'value']].agg('first')
)

The result is:

```
      variable  value
index
0        alpha    1.0
1        delta    1.0
2        alpha    NaN
3        bravo   -1.0
```